# How to set my Raspberry Pi to boot into the GUI?

Tags: boot, gui

As from my previous question, I asked what the power off button in the corner does. Then somebody said if you boot into the GUI automatically, it will give you some options.

How do I boot into the GUI at startup?

Comment: Can you expand on which distribution are you using?

Comment: Read this article which explains how to auto login and auto start desktop
http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Raspbian, it is actually rather simple to do what you ask. Simply open the terminal, and type in the following:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

The following window should show up

[image: Config Screen]

Navigate to `boot_behaviour` and click enter. This should make it so that the GUI interface starts automatically.

Comment: Just a detail: My feeb attempts to switch _back_, from boot-to-gui to boot-to-shell, failed. Maybe I started with an obsolete Raspbian image...

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux), please install the [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server. Follow the steps in [Archlinux Beginners Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Graphical_User_Interface) first. And install your favorite WM.

1. Add thise lines to your `~/.xinitrc`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   #
   # ~/.xinitrc
   #
   # Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

   if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
      for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
       [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
      done
      unset f
   fi
   exec openbox-session ## I'm using window manager Openbox (<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox>)
   #exec awesome
   ```
2. Start X when logging in. Add the following to the bottom of `~/.bash_profile` if you use `bash`. Or `~/.zprofile` if you're are using `zsh`. [See more on the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Login).

   [[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx

Comment: Note this works on raspbian as well. xxmbabanexx's answer didn't work for me (I think because I have a `.xinitrc`?), but I added `exec startx` to `~/.profile` and it's working now.