# Raspian gui unable to log in

Tags: gui, login, terminal

I'm new to Raspbian.

I started the GUI for the  first time (following a fresh install) using the instructions found here:
[How to set my Raspberry Pi to boot into the GUI?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/how-to-set-my-raspberry-pi-to-boot-into-the-gui)
and the command:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

I rebooted the machine, but the default login (pi) and password (raspberry) no longer work. I don't know of any other way to reset the password.

Other than re-flashing the Raspbian image to the SD card, how can I get out of this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a terminal makes no difference. Also there you are ask for a username and a password. But you can reset the password if you can mount the `ext4` root partition on another computer. Connect the SD Card with a card reader to a linux computer and mount the root partition to e.g. `/mnt`. Then edit

`/mnt/etc/passwd`

```
change
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
to
pi::1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

`/mnt/etc/shadow`

```
change
pi:ljrp9kgwknldgp80ooutqwwe06aswrjhgdhäthtltlehihifhiljlofwerndsl/RoIJcnHQ7kAzdXi3gN.Uw6kDFNLsJqtDZk0:17761:0:99999:7:::
to
pi::::
```

exact 4 colons are important.

Booting this in your RasPi you should be able to login without password: username pi, password just `<enter>`. If you want to do it on a terminal you can try the key combination `<ctrl><alt><F1>` when you are on the GUI. Most GUI switch with it to a terminal.

And yes, don't forget to give a new password.

Comment: Can you explain why my user and password are not working on the gui?

Comment: Any arbitrary password can be inserted into the `/etc/shadow` file if one uses the `mkpasswd` program to properly hash the password... `mkpasswd -m sha-512` should produce a correctly hashed password.

Comment: @frepie No, I don't know why user an password are not working. I don't know what you have done. Normally with a fresh fläshed Raspbian you will boot into the GUI. There is no need to set it up with `raspi-config` and there is no need to install another display manager `lightdm` like you did.