# Fresh new slackware arm install, unable to log into my raspberry pie 3

Tags: linux, root

I have been trying to install slackware arm (slackware arm current 4.19.81-7+) on my Raspberry pi 3. After i have installed it successfully (following [this guide](https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:arm:raspberrypi3)), i was unable to login due to the password being incorrect.

To my knowledge the default username is `root` and the default password is `password`, but i have also tried `passwd`, `root`, and nothing as a password, but none of them were correct, and i can't login. There were also no errors during boot.

I don't know were to begin looking, or what to do to solve this problem. can i get some help ? if my information were lacking just tell me and i will try to provide more info, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used slackware on Raspberry Pi so far but there is a generic way to reset the password as long as you have physical access to your device. You have to modify the files `/etc/password` and `/etc/shadow`. How to do it you can look at [Raspian gui unable to log in](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89102/79866).

Comment: Nice, it worked perfectly.